# jQuery Data Binding - What's the plugin that's popular these days?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I need some type of JS MVC, DataBinding solution. Similar to implementing a GMAIL Web App. Messages INDEX and Messages Show. where on the messages show, if you modify a message it updates in the messages index automatically.

What's the plugin that I should learn to make this work without crazy amounts of jQuery?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a job that [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/) could handle.  It allows you to associate DOM elements with a data model pretty easily.  Technically it's not MVC it's MVVM (model-view-viewmodel).

Comment: very interesting. I hadn't heard of this before.

Comment: Any idea how popular, supported knockoutjs is?

Comment: @AnApprentice: I'm not sure how well-supported it is.  My team hasn't run into too many issues with it.  That said, there are only 17 questions tagged with 'knockoutjs' on SO (that could be taken as a good *or* bad sign really).  You could check out the google groups page for a sense of how good the support is: http://groups.google.com/group/knockoutjs.  As for popularity; that's a good question, I didn't see a list of projects using it and Google isn't much help...

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/), which is built with [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/), both very well done and popular these days.

Neither builds on jQuery. However, both of them strive to be very expressive with minimal code, and as a result, they are both compact and lightweight.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at [JavaScriptMVC](http://javascriptmvc.com/). We've been using it for a while now and we are happy with it. Unlike other frameworks, it builds directly onto jQuery.

With it, you have a Model which has Attributes. You change an Attribute by calling something like myModel.attr("firstName", "Bob"). Anytime an Attribute changes, the model will fire an event. So your Controller (or anything) could register for myModel's "firstName" event, and you'll get notified when firstName changes, at which point you can update your view.

Answer (score 0):

All interesting solutions. I follow Ressig suggestions and articles: http://ajaxian.com/archives/jquery-data-binding-templates-and-mobile-john-resig-at-fowa

Answer (score 0):

Boris Moore is currently working on [JsViews & JsRender](http://www.borismoore.com/search/label/jQueryTemplates). It‘s already usable and going beta soon.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody coming across this question more recently, I think a great solution to data binding DOM elements to a model is [Generic Data Binder (GDB)](http://gdb.thewebdev.guru/). It's extremely simple and very flexible for these purposes. Check it out.