# How to show json object data into my view Layer(JSP)?

Tags: ajax, json, spring-mvc

In my project i am using springMVC+Hibernet .When **EndUser click his/her profile Link i want to show his/her Information** .For that i am using ajax in spring MVC .Now my controller return data in the form **JSON** object but i don't know How to update the object in my view Page.In That Object i have more than 25 fields any one help me how to update JSON object data to my jsp lables(FirstName,LastName.....)

MY code like this

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
 url: "AjaxActionController?",
 dataType: "json",

    success: function(data){
       alert(data);
     var firstName = data.getFristName();
     }
```

}
NOW i want to Update this data into my view layer

Answer (score 1):

One "simple" way to do it is to set an id on the html element you want the data in and use jQuery to set it.  This will get less and less "simple" as your application grows.

html:

```
<div id="firstName"/>
```

javascript:

```
success:function(data){
   var firstName = data.getFirstName();
   $('#firstName').text(firstName);
 }
```

If you want something more manageable for a large app, the concept is called "data binding".  Try a javascript databinding framework, such as [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/index.html), [Ember](http://emberjs.com/)/Backbone, [Angular](http://angularjs.org/), [Epoxy](http://epoxyjs.org/)/Backbone.  [jQuery can do it too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536490/jquery-data-binding-whats-the-plugin-thats-popular-these-days), with [some work](http://www.lucaongaro.eu/blog/2012/12/02/easy-two-way-data-binding-in-javascript/).